# There is garbage data in sql-query but it is still executing, although not affecting any results. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets, jdbc, sql-injection

I am using mysql server for sql.
`Select * from products some_garbage_value;`
and

```
Select * from products;
```

resulting the same value. Why?

Entering anything at the place of some_garbage_value, still result the same query result.

I have created a form to enter query and that form is handled by a servlet and after creating a connection, i am resulting the query result on that servlet.

Is this bad thing for my form, if yes then tell me, How to get rid of this bug? Is this a bug? Can it be a case of SQL Injection?

Comment: if that some_garbage_value is like "where 1 = 1" then it will return all the rows only. let me know some sample value of "some_garbage_value"

Comment: @Gaj sample value can be anything eg: gaj, stack, overflow, divyam, jain, abc123 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
Select * from products some_garbage_value;
```

The `some_garbage_value` is not garbage, it is an alias. Technically this means that for the scope of query, you have 'renamed' this occurrence of the `products` table to `some_garbage_value`. This can be very useful if you need to disambiguate between two occurrence of the same table (eg in self-join), or to make your query more readable/self-explanatory (or just shorter).

It is equivalent to

```
Select * from products as some_garbage_value;
```

See also the [MySQL reference for `select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> The `FROM table_references` clause indicates the table or tables from
>   which to retrieve rows. If you name more than one table, you are
>   performing a join. For information on join syntax, see Section
>   13.2.9.2, “JOIN Syntax”. For each table specified, you can optionally specify an alias.
>
> ```
> tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint]
> ```

This wouldn't work with just any value: it must be a syntactically valid identifier.